# PowerShell run on MacOS npm install error

Tags: javascript, protractor

help me please. I need will run my script for autotest with Azure and make npm install, but get error:

> protractor-tests@0.0.1 terminate-selenium
> PowerShell.exe ./Configuration/Scripts/terminateSelenium.ps1

sh: PowerShell.exe: command not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/macds/Desktop/project/ProtractorUiTests
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c npm run terminate-selenium

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macds/.npm/_logs/2021-12-12T22_06_57_607Z-debug.log
macds@macds ProtractorUiTests %

Comment: Well, sure. Powershell is a Windows program, it's not going to work anywhere else. So, fix your npm scripts to not rely on "only works on one specific OS" tools?

Comment: So sorry, i’m so wanted work on my  macos. But project for windows

Comment: It's almost certainly not, because you need to go out of your way to lock a Node codebased into a single OS, so someone just didn't want to take the effort to keep things cross-platform... that said, If this isn't your project: talk to the folks whose project it is, so they can update their run scripts to use normal cross-platform tools - and if it is your project, you'll have to talk about why you're using a _second_, but windows-only, scripting language (namely, PS) when you're _already_ using a universal scripting language (namely, Node).

Comment: Have you tried remove `sh -c` which should not work Windows without using additional tool.  `npm run terminate-selenium` should work in Windows, Linux and MacOS